# Overriding default Wordpress behavior in Admin Dashboard for sending headers with CSV generation

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm prototyping a WP plugin, using [a Plugin Boilerplate.](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate)  I'm finding it very difficult to generate documents and override the Admin Dashboard in WP IOT create pdfs/spreadsheets etc.  I'm sure there is a trick that I don't know.

If there is a best practice for this I'd love to know, as the traditional approaches I would take (with other frameworks) doesn't seem to work.

What I'm doing now is generating a menu page, with a submenu page.  The submenu page has links to generate various reports.  After reading the Codex, it's suggested to add a subpage menu page with the [parent slug as null](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) (so it's unlisted, but available).

Code looks like this:

```
$this->plugin_screen_hook_suffix = add_submenu_page(
            null,
            __( 'Session', $this->plugin_slug. '-reports' ),
            __( 'Session Report', $this->plugin_slug. '-reports' ),
            'manage_options',
            $this->plugin_slug . '-report-session',
            array( $this, 'display_plugin_session_report_page' )
        );

public function display_plugin_session_report_page() {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.csv;');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
//push out csv...
}
```

The only way I've had this work with WP is linking to an external page, like report.php, and calling the method within it.  Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I went with, which avoids setting up a separate script page:

In the URL, I add the following: `&noheader=true`, then in the function call I clear the output buffer using [ob_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) and generate my own headers. I was unable to locate any solid documentation on the noheader setting, but find that it is only applicable in the admin.php calls.

I hope this helps other developers!